# HikariDataSource ,PoolInitializationException, Too many connections

Tags: datasource, connection-pooling

I get an error "Server returned : Too many connections"
Now from the solutions I've gathered I have done the following

1. I have closed all my connections.
2. I have a port number used in the url.
3. I have used either dataSourceClassName or DriverClassName(never
   both).
4. I have increased the maxPoolSize to 100 which I think is not 
   right(ideally be 30-35) and increased idletimeout as well.

Can someone elaborate on dataSourceClassName and what my be wrong with my code??

//My CODE below

```
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDataSourceClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"); 
     config.addDataSourceProperty("url", url); 
     config.addDataSourceProperty("user", dbuser);
     config.addDataSourceProperty("password", dbpassword);
     config.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
```

//Throws error at the below line that follows the above code

```
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

in point 4 you say: maxPoolSize to 100 which I think is not right (ideally be 30-35)

later you wrote
//My CODE below
config.setMaximumPoolSize(**10000**);

also check max_connections in my.cnf / my.ini. default is 151 which is ok.

Comment: Sorry ! edit made.  
max_connections in my.cnf was 100 and then i changed it to 200. The error still persists

Comment: change config.setMaximumPoolSize(10000); to 100 or remove it entirely.

Comment: that doesn't fix the issue. I dont believe it to be a config problem, Anyway can you throw some light on dataSourceClassName and DriverClassName ?

Comment: 'paste' config that throws exception and the stack trace